# How to install ete2 on Python 2.7?

Tags: python, module, failed-installation, etetoolkit

I have looked at some other questions about module installation and Python documentation, but I cannot succeed in installing ete2 on Python 2.7.

I have already downloaded it from the website, but have no idea what my next step should be.

Comment: You should at least mention 1) the OS you're trying to install on 2) what instructions you have been following, and 3) what errors you encountered.

Comment: check here:  http://etetoolkit.org/download/

Answer (score 0):

On macOS, the following command worked with Python 2.7:

`pip install --upgrade ete2`

Please refer the documentation given on [etetoolkit.org](http://etetoolkit.org/download/).